# I am new to regular expression can someone help me convert this to regular expression using Python?

Tags: python

A valid number is defined by the following rules:

1. can have any number of digits, but it can have only digits and a decimal point and possibly a leading sign.
2. the decimal point is optional, but if it appears in the number, there must be only one, and it must have digits on its left and its right.
3. There should be whitespace or a beginning or end-of-line character on either side of a valid number.

`valid = re.findall(r'\s\d\.\d\s', text)`

This is what I have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `+` after the digits to allow more than one.

Make the decimal point and digits after it optional by putting them in a group followed by `?`.

The whitespace after the number should be a lookahead. Otherwise, you won't be able to find two consecutive numbers, since `re.findall()` won't return overlapping matches. But you can't use a lookbehind for the whitespace before the number, because lookbehinds have to be fixed length, and the combination of a space or beginning of line is variable length.

```
text = '9 foobar 123 abc45 3.21 4.5'
valid = re.findall(r'(?:\s|^)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s|$)', text)
print(valid)
```

prints

```
['9', ' 123', ' 3.21', ' 4.5']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r'(?:\s|^)(\d+\.\d+|\d+)(?=\s|$)'
```

Either match one or more digits followed by exactly one `.` followed by one or more digits.

```
(\d+\.\d+|\d+)
```

Look for a whitespace or beginning of line ahead, but don't consume it.

```
(?:\s|^)
```

Look for a trailing whitespace or endline, but don't include it in the match.

```
(?=\s|$)
```